# How do I output specific characters from a txt file to specific points?

Tags: c++

First task of the tutorial and I'm already stumped,

Right, I'm supposed to write down 3 numbers into a text file, open that file up, output all 3 numbers and the average. Managed to get the first 2 parts done but I've hit a wall at the actual output part.

Here is the contents of the text file exactly as it appears within the file:

> 25
>
> 10
>
> 12

And here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// Create an ifstream input stream for reading of data from the file
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("ProgrammingIsFun.txt");

// Create an ofstream output stream for writing data to a file
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("Results.out");



cout << "The first integer is " << endl;
cout << "The second integer is " << endl;
cout << "The third integer is " << endl;
cout << "The average is " << endl;

// Close the files since we're done with them
outFile.close();
inFile.close();

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

From what I understand the contents of the txt file can only contain those 3 numbers and nothing else (I could be wrong though)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's just the shell of the full program, I'm expecting it to read as:
The first integer is 25
The second integer is 10
The third integer is 12
The average is whatever

Comment: You aren't reading the numbers from `inFile`, and you aren't computing the average, and you aren't writing the result to `outFile`. Which of these three are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the preferred C++ way of reading integers from files would be:

```
int first, second, third;

inFile >> first;
inFile >> second;
inFile >> third;
```

You can then analogously output using the << operator on outFile.